# What is 'result' in Win8 JS code: WinJS.xhr({urlhere}).done(function complete(result) { });

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

See the following line of code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://someurl.com" }).then(
          function fulfilled(result)
          {
             if (result.status === 200)
             {
                resDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
                resDiv.innerText = "Success";
             }
          });
```

As far as I understand, when WinJS.xhr has completed whatever it does **then** execute the anonymous function 'fulfilled' with argument 'result'

Coming from Java/C++ background, I'm extremely confused with how this code works - how is 'result' being passed to this function? Where does it say anything about what 'result' is? How can I know what type of object 'result' is and how it has a 'status' member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to break my answer into two parts: The first concerns the actual execution model of Javascript, and the second which concerns the high-level expression as written.

### The Javascript Execution Model

1. `WinJS` evaluates to an object.
2. That object has a prototype which contains an `xhr` member which `WinJS.xhr` evaluates to. That member is a function, which we will refer to as `A` below so that we can keep clear what exactly is going on.
3. Before we get to that, `{ url: "http://someurl.com" }` returns an object which we will refer to as `B`.
4. That object `B` has a property called `url`.
5. `A(B)` calls a function `A` with a value `B` as an argument. It *returns* an object that we will refer to as `C`.
6. That object `C` has a prototype which contains a member named `then`. `C.then` happens to evaluate to a function. That function we will refer to as `D`.
7. `function fulfilled(result) {...}` returns a function that we will refer to as `E`. It can also be referred to as `fulfilled` but that fact is not used in this program fragment.
8. `D(E)` calls a function `D` with a value `E` as an argument. Nothing is done with the return value.

### The high-level view

There are three functions here; one is a callback (called `fulfilled`), and the other two may be called "methods"- one `xhr` of the `WinJS` global object, and `then` of a promise object.

`WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://someurl.com" })` creates and returns that [promise object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx). You can convince yourself of this by consulting [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx).

The promise object has a method called `then` which registers what you can think of as an event handler for when the promise is *done*. The value `result` - used in that callback registered in `then` comes from whatever is making that promise *done* by in fact calling the method `done` on that promise. You don't see the code that does that because it's someplace in the implementation of `WinJS.xhr`.

What `WinJS.xhr` is doing is performing a network request. When that network request is *done* it will signal the result of that network request (which according to the documentation is an [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object) through the promise by calling the `done()` method on that promise. That in-turn calls the callback we registered with the `then()` method.

Comment: Thank you. I had to read and re-read this several times, but I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

The [`xhr` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) returns a [`Promise` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx), which has the [`then` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229728.aspx) that takes the `onComplete`, `onError` and `onProcress` callback functions.

This code only uses the `onComplete` callback. The callback is called when the request is completed, and it's sent a parameter with the value sent from the server.

If you are not familiar will callback functions, it may be clearer if you declare a regular function an use as the callback:

```
function fulfilled(result) {
  if (result.status === 200) {
    resDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
    resDiv.innerText = "Success";
  }
}

WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://someurl.com" }).then(fulfilled);
```

The `then` method is intended for pre-processing the result, you should rather use the [`done` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701079.aspx) to take care of the result.

I haven't found anything in the documentation that specifies exactly in what form the value comes from the server. It's probably there somewhere, but as usual with Microsoft documentation, it's rather complete but everything isn't everywhere so you have to look in different places to find specific information.

Comment: Yeah I understand that much - I'm just not understanding how the 'result' is passed into the 'fulfilled' function. Please see my reply to carlosfigueira's answer

Comment: @Arvin: It's rather like a function pointer that you pass to the `then` method, which it then uses to call the function. As functions are first class members in Javascript, a function reference can be passed around like any other value, so there is no special syntax needed to make a function reference. You just use the name of the function without parentheses (or the value of an anonymous function creation, like in the example). It might be easier if you declare a regular function; see my edit above.

Comment: I see - and so result is whatever the then function is called on?

Comment: @Arvin: The `result` parameter is whatever that object decides to call the callback function with, in this case something that represents the response from the server. The reference to your function is stored in the object, and when later on the response from the server arrives, your function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the WinJS functions is still not great, IMO. You can look at the documentation for `WinJS.xhr` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx, and that will give you some information on that - it says that the `xhr` function "wraps ... XMLHttpRequest object in a promise". Personally I've found it easier to look at the examples / quickstarts than at the reference documentations.

What you have passed to the `fulfilled` function (or the first function there) isn't the "result" of the operation, but the `XMLHttpRequest` object itself. On that you can get its properties to see the result - take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms535874.aspx for its reference.

Comment: Right, so xhr basically returns a XMLHttpRequest wrapped as a promise, which has a then function. What I'm still confused about is how is the XMLHttpRequest itself passed into the argument of a function declaration inside the then function? Is this just a feature of javascript? Or is this something that Microsoft has created

Comment: This is standard practice in JavaScript (although other languages have that as well). You often pass a function to another, and the documentation tells you which parameter the function you passed should expect.

Comment: For example, jQuery's `each` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function applies to arrays, and it takes a function as a parameter which receive the items of the array being enumerated. IMO the jQ documentation page is better than the MSDN for `WinJS.xhr`, as it clearly states what the function expects.